# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Column Justification when hiding fields

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

We have a display issue with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.  We have a large customized form, and we show and hide various things based on data on the form (usually the owner and a few other lookup values).  The problem we have is that the forms are very ugly.  We have two columns, and when we hide something in the left column, it will cause the item adjacent to it in the right column to move over.  We would like things to stay in their columns, and flow upward to fill gaps.

Has anyone had experience with this and is this possible?  I'm hoping there's a javascript solution to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some CRM documentation this is caused by the way the page and DOM elements get loaded, and setting the display to none on the disappearing elements will keep the structure better.  However, while trying this, it still loaded the incorrect way, so I tried another solution.

I tacked on the new fields in their own section.  Visually it isn't perfect, but it at least forces them to stay on the right side.